# IONIC - Meu projeto não gera a pasta www

Tags: ionic

Fiz a instalação normal do ionic, segui os passos e etc. Depois de criar o meu projeto e acessar no visual studio code, não tem a pasta www . Reparei que em todas as video aulas na internet, todos geram essa pasta. O que devo fazer ?

Comment: Qual a versão do Ionic que você está utilizando ( use o comando `ionic info` para descobrir ) ? Porque pode ser que, a versão do Ionic dos seus videos de estudo seja uma antiga, as versões v3 e v4 não possuem mais essa pasta.

Comment: Acho que é isso mesmo que você disse. O vídeo deve ser antigo. ionic 4.6.0. Eu pensei que me projeto não tendo esta pasta, nunca daria certo

Comment: Não se preocupe, a sua versão do Ionic não necessita dessa pasta. Procure videos sobre a versão mais nova e você não terá problemas.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

dependendo da versão do ionic a pasta www não é mais necessária, mas caso precise, você pode criar esta pasta manualmente sem nenhum problema, pode ser uma pasta vazia mesmo que ele vai funcionar normalmente